# nw reactjs requring in multiple files does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-webkit

problem-

```
var React= require('react')
var SomeComponent= require('./utils/SomeComponent')
var Wrapper= React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <SomeComponent/>
    }
})

//utils/SomeComponent.js:
var React= require('react')
module.exports= React.createClass({ 
    //..
})
```

throws- `Error: Invariant Violation: Wrapper.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

no errors when used in one file

(by the way

```
var React= require('react')
```

throws `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

after lot of googling I solved that by calling

```
global.document= window.document
global.navigator= window.navigator
```

Maybe it's related?)

Comment: This sounds very strange... can you explain more about what environment you're running this in?

Comment: just a tiny node-webkit app

Comment: Are both files loaded only on the webkit side of the node/webkit divide?

Comment: yes. the main file loaded by script tag and the second required by it

Comment: To set global.document and global.navigator properly, you can use jsdom. `var document = require("jsdom").jsdom("<html><head></head><body></body></html>"),  window = document.createWindow(),`

Comment: You can also consider using atom electron (http://electron.atom.io/) instead of nw for your desktop javascript development. That's what I ended up doing when I made the move to es6+react.